# How to reuse code from iPhone project for iPad project? Which way is the best?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ipad

I started a company project for about 1 year for iPhone devices. This year,  I will start the project for the Ipad device, the feature the same but different layout. My problem, how to reuse that code for Ipad? Which way is the best?

My workspace includes an iPhone project and Pod project.

Thank All.

Comment: It is better to have a single project that is "universal" - i.e. supports both iPhone and iPad devices.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11. Currently, My project was "universal", but the iPad layout just scale bigger, but requirements for the iPad layout different from the iPhone layout, and I don't want to increment the app size. :(

Comment: I think you can build a framework for business logic classes so that you can share with either iPhone or iPad project.

Comment: Hi @ThangPhung. You Use the Same Code for iPhone and iPad, but you need to manage you layout for iPad, you can manage your layout Using Size Class.

Comment: `universal ` project is good option for you. But if you still think to separate you can `Creating a separate build scheme` for your `iPad`

Comment: Hi @KrunalNagvadia. Yup, I am thinking about this solution. I will create a new target and checkmark file and storyboard if need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If UI has major changes then create a new storyboard for the iPad and use the same outlets and classes, you don't need to re-write the code. Just design new ui and attach outlets.

Comment: Hi @sDev. I also think about this, but does it increase the size app when building? Because It uses both storyboard iPhone and iPad.

Comment: You can use app thinking at the time of app uploading so it will not increase size.

Comment: and it will use the respective storyboard at the time of archive.

Comment: If there is no bigger changes in UI then use a single storyboard and use size classes for adoptive layout.

Comment: Hi @sDev. Because of iPhone UI and iPad UI too big differences, I think I should separate storyboards. I will try your solution. Thanks for your help.